# Pivot two yields into a single table in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, home-assistant

I want to combine two search results into a single table with InfluxDB on home assistant. After many hours of research I can't seem to find what I would think is a simple solution so any suggestions appreciated. Here is my code

```
from(bucket: "HomeAssistant/autogen")
  |> range(start: 2022-11-01T00:00:00Z, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "total_energy")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "total_kwh")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 24h, fn: max)
  |> yield(name: "today")
  |> timeShift(duration: 24h)
  |> yield(name: "tomorrow")
```

The above creates two query results named "today" and "tomorrow" time-shifted 24hrs apart. I want to pivot both results into a single table with columns names "today" and "tomorrow" but struggling to find a simple syntax without doing multiple queries with joins or creating dummy columns with labels. Is there a straight forward way to pivot these two yields into a single table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two tables into one by using the [group function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/group-data/)
When omitting all parameters this function should create one table out of multiple tables.
I used it for example, when a tag can have multiple values and I don't want to get a table for each possible value.

I don't know what your data looks like, so here is an example from me:

```
from(bucket: "monitoring")
    |> range(start: -24h, stop: now())
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "container_logs")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "message")
    |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop", "_field", "_measurement", "host", "hostname"])
    |> group()
    |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: false)
```

This would produce one table with columns _time, tag1, tag2, _value. Without `group()` I would get a table for each tag value.
Hope this helps you. Otherwise try to provide some test data.